# Rails/Postgres treat string column as integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I got a table named companies and a column named employees, which is a string column.
My where condition to find companies which have between 10 and 100 employees:

```
where("companies.employees >= ? AND companies.employees <= ?", 10, 100)
```

The problem is: The column needs to remain a string column so I can't just convert it to integer but I also want to compare the employee numbers. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use a cast. But really, that's ghastly database modelling, storing integers in string columns.

Comment: I know that it's not the right way in general but I got no other options at the moment. I know that a cast would be the right option but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Could you answer the question with the right syntax maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work, it is a ruby question, I don't know ruby :-)  In postgres I would write the query as Craig says, like this:

```
select * from companies where employees::integer >= 10 and employees::integer <= 100;
```

(Of course there is substitution, etc, but this gets the concept across.  One of the problems you run in to when you don't use the correct type in postgres is that indices don't work right.  Since you are casting the employees to an integer type, you have to fetch every record, convert it to an integer, then filter using the greater/less than stuff.  Every record in the table will be fetched, casted, then compared.  If this was an integer type to start with, and there was an index on the table, then the postgres engine can do a lot better performance wise by selecting only the relevant records. Anyway...

Your ruby may work modified like this:

```
where("companies.employees::integer >= ? AND companies.employees::integer <= ?", 10, 100)
```

But, that makes me curious about the substitution.  If the type is gleaned from the type of the argument, then it might work because the 10 and 100 are clearly integers.  If the substitution gets weird, you might be able to do this:

```
where("companies.employees::integer >= cast(? as integer) AND companies.employees::integer <= cast(? as integer)", 10, 100)
```

You can use that syntax for the entire query as well:

```
where("cast(companies.employees as integer) >= cast(? as integer) AND  cast(companies.employees as integer) <= cast(? as integer)", 10, 100)
```

One of these variants might work.  Good Luck.

-g